# How to fix png image issue in IE6?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6, iepngfix

I know there are many ways available on internet, I found one with using [iepngfix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) , but to resolve this issue i need to specify width and height to each png image and its too time consuming process for me. Because i have 1000's of png images in my project, Is there any way to resolve this issue without specifying width and height to image tag,

My image tag is :

```
<img src="myPngImage.png" width="120" height="100" />
```

Comment: The best fix of IE6 issues is to drop IE6 as a supported browser. It always was, always is, and always will be, and absolute piece of moronic crap. Make your life easier and forget it exists.

Comment: This has been answered 100 times already. Go find an existing answer.

Comment: Just a reminder to some people that there are still users who use IE6. As web designers working for companies we sometimes don't have a choice; we can't tell our boss or our client to upgrade their browser. Yes in a pure modern would we could forget about our past sins, but we still get haunted by old browsers. Please be a bit more constructive with your criticism web designers who still have to deal with IE6.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at CSSPie, I use it personally and so far it works great. I didn't test for images transparency in IE6 but seems to be well-supported http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-png-fix.

Comment: Beat me too it by seconds. Probably the most robust solution but the best one for all of us would be not to support a 10 year old browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you must support IE6, then I recommend using something like [jquery's capabilities](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aPNG_Opacity_Fix_for_IE6) (which will auto detect the width/height of images).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
      <script src="js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            DD_belatedPNG.fix('img,div,ul,li,li a,a,input,p,blockquote,span,h1,h2,h3');
      </script>
      <![endif]-->
```

download code from here

http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/pkToolkitPlugin/trunk/web/js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js?rev=20453

or

customize-your-blogger.googlecode.com/files/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js